# Ways to remove mysterious space of Html, Body after footer in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to CSS responsive coding. I've used a premade boostrap template and modified it. Its working fine. The only issue is when this website is viewed on Firefox responsive design tool at different size a mysterious white space appears after the footer.

Check the screenshot below for the mysterious white space being shown when i try to view the webpage on Firefox responsive design tool at: 768x1024 . How do we remove or hide this extra space ? I have tried; overflow:hidden; but its not working. Check this [Website Link](http://hahahah.asia/landing/) for the online version of the page

Please check the image screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Your website link and screenshot link both point to a screenshot. From what I can tell you page doesn't have enough content to fill the viewport.

Comment: You have any code (css, html) to share?

Comment: your website link is another image, please provide the correct link. Just by looking at the image I can tell that your page probably has a `div` with with both 100% width and height, but the inside image has 100% width only. This setup is probably causing an empty space when you resize the page.

Comment: I have fixed the link above, please check it. Thanks for checking the screenshot. @ScarletMerlin  . Also, hungerstar and zgood thanks for checking.

Comment: Nothing, tested it out with safari, chrome and Firefox. I can't see the white space.

Comment: oh, did you try the Firefox built-in Responsive Designer ? When i view the website through Firefox responsive designer tool  i can see the bottom Space. Please check this http://hahahah.asia/landing/stacko2.png image screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That space is due to the site not being 'long or tall enough' for that specific device. You can fix it by instead of using `height:auto` on your `.wrapper` element, use `height:100vh`.

```
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100vh !important;
    margin: 0px auto -155px;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

`100vh` will get the vertical height of the specific viewport that it is being used on so it will always take up the screen.

Here is a little more on **[Vertical Viewport Heights](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the valuable inputs. I just tried and now the white space is being covered by black space. So, you are saying if my website is not tall enough, on a taller device there will be space ? Is there a work-around to have my website look normal even when viewed on a taller device?

I just want to cut out that extra space, is it possible? Or reduce / hide the extra space . Thanks again

Comment: You will have space if say your site is only 3/4s the screen size of an ipad, they'll fill that space with the body color. Some options you have are to make a media query for that specific screen size and spread your stuff out or some people use fixed navs to take up some space.

Answer (score 0):

It is your footer element which is at the bottom of the page.

```
.footer, .push {
  height: 155px;
}
```

Also, your fix is a greasy on and won't work always:

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto -155px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable inputs. What do you recommend i should do ? I'm re-writing the same page from scratch now.